# Setting 2 second delay not working in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am displaying 2 second fading animation in view class, after 2-secs, I want to go to viewmodel class to run which load login page or signup page logic

right now its skipping 2 sec animation and going directly to viewmodel. idk what the issue is here

if i delete line `BindingContext = new SplashscreenViewModel();` than animation shows up but it doesnt go to viewmodel class

SplashscreenPage.xaml.cs - view class

```
    public SplashscreenPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Animation();
        BindingContext = new SplashscreenViewModel();
    }

    async void Animation()
    {
        ssImage.Opacity = 0;
        await Task.WhenAll(
            ssImage.FadeTo(1, 2000),
            ssImage.ScaleTo(1.1, 2000)
            );
    }//end of method
```

Splashscreen - viewmodel class

```
 public SplashscreenViewModel()
        {
            WhichPageToLoad();
        }
 
  async void WhichPageToLoad()
    {

            var getToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Save_Pin_1");
            if(getToken == null)
            {
                var route = $"{ nameof(SignupPage)}";
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
            }
            else
            {
                var route = $"{ nameof(LoginPage)}";
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
            }
}
```

Comment: i tried moving animation to viewmodel class, but i can't seem to call FadeTo inside viewmodel class and bind to view class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is really no point in having a VM class or assigning the `BindingContext` since you are not doing any databinding.  You can just call the navigation code after the animation completes.  You cannot make async calls from the constructor, so moving the animation and navigation login into `OnAppearing` will allow you to make an async call

```
public SplashscreenPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
}

async override void OnAppearing()
{
    ssImage.Opacity = 0;

    await Task.WhenAll(
        ssImage.FadeTo(1, 2000),
        ssImage.ScaleTo(1.1, 2000)
        );

    var getToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Save_Pin_1");
      
    if(getToken == null)
        {
            var route = $"{ nameof(SignupPage)}";
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
        }
        else
        {
            var route = $"{ nameof(LoginPage)}";
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
        }
}
```

Comment: thank @Jason. I was too busy trying to move everything to viewmodel.... i forgot i could just move to view. your solution worked for me